# Java applet sets cookie on browser when i call setRequestProperty

Tags: java, cookies, browser

I am using URLconnection to send data in an applet ,

this is my code :

```
URL url = new URL("http://example.com");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("cookie", cookie_val);
```

in this case ,the value of cookie is set in the browser , but i dont want that , the cookie is just for internal use in applet . how can i revoke cookie transfert to the browser ?

Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by adding a default  cookiehandler

```
CookieManager manager = new CookieManager();
manager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);
```

that prevent cookies to be stored on browser ..